# Configuring Codeigniter with Tank Auth

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

Something in my CI configuration is missing a "/" that Tank auth view files are expecting and I can't figure it out. I hope you can!

Here are some details: 
`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CI/';`

I do not have .htaccess set up (so I still have index.php in my URI)

When Tank auth loads one of its view files, here is the first line: 
`<?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string()); ?>`

The resulting URI fails to load since it reads as "`http://localhost/CI/index.php?auth/register` instead of `http://localhost/CI/index.php/auth/register`

But, if I modify it to: 
`<?php echo form_open("/".$this->uri->uri_string()); ?>`
all is well. But this is now how it was meant to work!  What did I miss?

Thanks!

Comment: So what does the modified version return? Does it return the correct uri for the action? Why can't you just use "/auth/register" instead?

Comment: once I modify the tank auth file, it seems to work fine. Seems like the library works for everyone else without modification and so I suspected my own settings.

Comment: ah, maybe check to see if you have query strings on in your main config file?  I remember there was a setting similar to that...  Also, I remember having to modify tank auth quiet a bit for it to run smoothly for me (though I was using a .htaccess), if it doesn't deal with the security (and changing that wouldn't) of the library I see no reason why not to, even if it feels odd.

Comment: Oh ok - I'll take another look at the config file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just remove the index.php using .htaccess? That would solve the problem and give you cleaner URL's.

Here't the rewrite I used for my installation of Tank Auth on my localhost.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~Steve/_sandbox/tank_auth/index.php/$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: Thanks @Prefontaine. This answer helped me a lot with my long weird issue in rewriting url(s).